# Illustrator trim not cutting cleanly

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects, pathfinder

I have two shapes as seen below

[image]

I want to be able to trim the rectangle so that it doesn't flow into the inside of the circle. When I use Pathfinder's **trim** option it does not trim correctly as seen below:

[image]

I want the rectangle to wrap cleanly around the edge of the circle, but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You applied the rounded corners effect to your rectangle, you need to expand it first.

Go to **Object → Expand Appearance** in order to convert the rounded rectangle into an actual path.

Once you do that you can use pathfinder on the shape.